# Is it possible to communicate with AnyLogic at runtime from Python?

Tags: python, anylogic

Is it possible to communicate with AnyLogic at runtime from Python? I am working on a digital twin model where we can intelligently run experiments to set model parameters of the real system and was exploring whether this would be easier in Python or fully in AnyLogic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question invites a "yes" or "no" answer Is that what you really want?

Comment: [AnyLogic Cloud API: Python](https://www.anylogic.com/blog/python-api-for-simulations-in-anylogic-cloud/)

Answer (score 1):

Python Library

```
pip install https://cloud.anylogic.com/files/api-8.5.0/clients/anylogiccloudclient-8.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

**Code for a Basic Queue**

## Load anylogiccloudclient library

```
from anylogiccloudclient.client.cloud_client import CloudClient
```

## Create a CloudClient object, given the API key

```
client = CloudClient("e05a6efa-ea5f-4adf-b090-ae0ca7d16c20")
```

## Obtain latest model version of "Service System Demo" model

```
version = client.get_latest_model_version("Service System Demo")
```

## Create an Inputs object with the default input values

```
inputs = client.create_inputs_from_experiment(version, "Baseline")
```

## Change the "Server Capacity" parameter value

```
inputs.set_input("Server capacity", 8)
```

## Creat a simulation object with the inputs

```
simulation = client.create_simulation(inputs)
```

## Obtain the simulation outputs

```
outputs = simulation.get_outputs_and_run_if_absent()
```

## Print the simulation model outcome values

```
print("Raw outputs = " + str(outputs.get_raw_outputs()))
print("For Server Capacity = " + str(inputs.get_input("Server capacity")))
print("Mean queue size = " + str(outputs.value("Mean queue size|Mean queue size")))
print("Server utilization = " + str(outputs.value("Utilization|Server utilization")))
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with anylogic pypeline for example...

You can find it here:

```
https://github.com/t-wolfeadam/AnyLogic-Pypeline
```